# How to conditionally display custom tag in react jsx

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to conditionally display a custom tag based on the value of a variable in React.

The value is coming from the form context.

ex:

```
return( 
   ...

   (formContext = {
       const variable = getVariable() // returns a string

   
....

   <custom tag> </custom tag>
```

I want to display custom tag only if the variable value matches a certain string for ex:
if variable is "DISP" only then display the tag.

please & thanks.

please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: What tag do you want to display? Does `getVariable` returns the tag name? Or you just want to [conditionally render](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) a custom tag when a condition is true?

Comment: getVariable returns just a string. I want to display the tag based on the value of that string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use conditional rendering for this.

```
return (
  { (variable === "string") && <customTag></customTag> }
)
```

To learn more about conditional rendering, you could read this: [https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#:~:text=Inline%20If%20with%20Logical%20%26%26%20Operator&text=Therefore%2C%20if%20the%20condition%20is,will%20return%20the%20falsy%20expression](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#:%7E:text=Inline%20If%20with%20Logical%20%26%26%20Operator&text=Therefore%2C%20if%20the%20condition%20is,will%20return%20the%20falsy%20expression).

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional rendering

```
{ (variable === "DISP") && <custom tag> </custom tag> }
```